# permission to class some fields of ViewSet method Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, drf-queryset, django-viewsets

I want `AllowAny` permission only for the `retrieve` function. In my ViewSets.

```
class PostLanguageViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    permission_classes_per_method = {
        "retrieve": permission_classes
    }

    def retrieve(self, request, post_id=None, post_language_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

    def destroy(self, request, post_id=None, post_language_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

    def update(self, request, post_id=None, post_language_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

- this method allows all function permission `AllowAny`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
class PostLanguageViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return [permissions.AllowAny()]
        else:
            return super().get_permissions()
```

Comment: Is there any other method to do the same things???

Comment: Sorry. I only know this way.

Comment: This looks like a valid solution to your problem

Comment: Sorry. I fixed the parameters of the get_permissions method.
(self, request) -> (self)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be specific to action and not method. You can check the action and apply the permission accordingly.

```
    class PostLanguageViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
        def get_permissions(self):
            if self.action == 'retrieve':
                return [permissions.AllowAny()]
            return super().get_permissions()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use action decorator to achieve this this will override permissions and much more.

`````
class PostLanguageViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AnyOtherPermissionForOtherMethods]

    @action(
        methods=("GET",),
        url_path="get-language",
        url_name="get-language",
        detail=True,
        permission_classes=[
            permissions.AllowAny],
    )
    def retrive_language(self, request, post_id=None, post_language_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        #Your Code

    def destroy(self, request, post_id=None, post_language_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

    def update(self, request, post_id=None, post_language_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
        ````
`````

Comment: Not, Working... same ``` "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." ```

Comment: Add authentication_classes=[] in action decorator and check

Comment: Still getting...

Comment: please share code